# Configure Cloudfront with multiple s3 origins using different domains

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How can I configure a Cloudfront distribution to use multiple s3 origins with same hierarchy but using different domain names?

Currently I have a Cloudfront distribution with a distribution domain name for example `xyz.cloudfront.net`.

The distribution has been configured to use an alternate domain e.g. `assets.example.com` and to serve content using that domain I've added cname record in my DNS management console that maps `assets.example.com` to `xyz.cloudfront.net`.

Now this set up works fine when serving content from a single s3 origin as i can call something like `assets.example.com/images/my-image.png`

However I want to configure 3 s3 origins as follows which have identical hierarchies i.e. they all have an images folder:

```
dev-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
test-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
live-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

If I've configured `assets.example.com` to map to the distribution `xyz.cloudfront.net`, how is cloudfront going to know which origin to serve from?

basically if im running the dev website i want cloudfront to serve content from the dev origin and  if im running the test site then i want it to serve using the test origin.

The only way i can see how can i achieve this is creating 3 different cloud front distribution for each environment and map different domains to the distribution e.g. `assets-dev.example.com`, `assets-test.example.com` and `assets.example.com` for the live site.

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: I would highly recommend using different distributions for different environments. It doesn't look good to serve development content in the production domain.